# Async.map - make it ignore the error(s), and process the entire list

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have to process an array with **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async#map)**

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
Async.map(arr, iterator, callback);
```

The `iterator` function, which I have no control over, would throw errors for all values but, say `4`.

```
function iterator(val, cb) {
    console.debug('processing', val);
    if (val == 4) cb();
    else cb(new Error(val));
}
```

What async would do is

> If `iterator` passes an error to his callback, the main `callback` (for the `map` function) is immediately called with the error.

So I get

```
processing 1
[Error: 1]
processing 2
processing 3
processing 4
```

What I want is that it *shouldn't* immediately call the `callback` with an error, but wait til it processes the entire list, which it does anyways, and only then call the `callback`.

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative to Async.map that behaves in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If iterator passes an error to his callback, the main callback (for the map function) is immediately called with the error

https://github.com/caolan/async#map

You could instead pass back a null value to the callback instead of erroring out.

```
function iterator(cb, trans) {
  try {
    // something
    cb(null, transformed);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    // log the error perhaps
    cb(null, null);
  }
}
```

Since you don't have control over the iterator you could write a wrapper around it.

Assume their iterator is called `their_iterator`.

```
function my_iterator(cb, trans) {
  var my_cb = function(their_err, their_trans) {
    if (their_err) {
      // log error
        cb(null, null);
    }
    else {
        cb(null, their_trans);
    }
  }

  their_iterator(my_cb, trans);
}

Async.map(arr, my_iterator, callback);
```

Comment: I'm so sorry but I think I misspoke, the iterator function isn't under my control actually. I can't make changes to it

Comment: You could write a wrapper around the iterator function

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my iterator would send me nulls to my array, so I used `async.mapLimit` function.

`mapLimit(coll, limit, iteratee, callback)`

See:

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

I hope this helps.